# Displaying 2D array in grid calendar format in Processing

Tags: multidimensional-array, datagrid, storage, processing

I'm trying to modify this code so it appears in a grid layout with numbers ranging from 1-100 in descending order. I'm new to Java and the Processing program. This has to be done in Processing using Processing Java functions. This is the Code I have to modify, any small tips on how I should go about turning that into the image below

```java
int[][] numbers = new int[10][10];
void setup(){
  size(420,420);
  // you will have to initialise the array slots here
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++){
      text(numbers[i][j],20+i*40, 20+j*40);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Gride Layout]

Each and every piece of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```java
// you will have to initialise the array slots here
```

Filling in that section is your entire assignment. So, how do we initialize the array slots?

The `numbers` array is a **2D array**, meaning that it's an array of arrays. We can google something like "java initialize 2d array" for a ton of results, or we could look at this section of the code:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < numbers[0].length; j++){
     text(numbers[i][j],20+i*40, 20+j*40);
 }
}
```

This **nested for loop** is a big hint, as it iterates over the array and accesses each index. You need to do the same thing, but you need to initialize each index instead. Here's how you would initialize a single index:

```java
numbers[5][5] = 123;
```

You need to combine all of that information to accomplish your goal. Try breaking it down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Can you initialize the 2d array? Don't worry about what you're initializing them to. Maybe make them all the same number.

**Step 2:** Can you use the nested loop to make them all a different number? Might be easiest to put them in order 1-100 first.

**Step 3:** Then after you get that working, can you initialize them in the correct reversed order?